# Is 'who' here a relative word or an interrogative pronoun?

Tags: relative-clauses, questions

> (1) *That's a big part of **who I am**.*
>
> (2) *When that day comes if you don't like **who you are**, you're done.*

At first blush, the ***who***'s in (1) and (2) seem to be relative words in the fused construction.

CaGEL* (Page 1077), however, seems to say that both these are interrogative pronouns. Specifically, CaGEL says this:

[image]
...
[image]

An example of the free choice construction is:

> *Invite **who you like**.*

And I don't think the boldfaced expression in (1) or (2) is the free choice construction.

Does this mean that the ***who***'s in (1) and (2) are interrogative pronouns?

### EDIT

Here's what CaGEL (Page 1076-77) says about 'how' marginally occurring in a fused relative:

> Examples with *how* are found but they are rare and quite marginal:
>
> %*We will not change **how we use future contracts during the term of this Prospectus***; %*I don’t like **how it looks**.*

These examples are construed by CaGEL as possible -- admittedly marginally so -- cases of *how* occurring in a fused relative.

Now, returning to example (2) above, I don't know why *you don't like **who you are*** should be interpreted differently than *I don’t like **how it looks***. That is, if the latter's ***how*** is construed as a fused relative word, albeit marginally, then why shouldn't the former's *who* be?

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language by Huddleston & Pullum

Comment: (1) and (2) are interrogatives. "Who" – unlike what” or “whoever” – cannot normally occur in the fused relative construction, except in the 'free choice' construction, which they are not -- note also that you can't say *"Who I am is none of your concern". The meaning of (1) for example can be glossed as "That's a big part of the answer to the question 'Who am I?'"

Comment: @BillJ You say you can't say _Who I am is none of your concern_, but I've found a few examples in Google Books:  https://goo.gl/UscBdV Are these all ungrammatical?

Comment: @BillJ Also, I've added EDIT to my question.

Comment: What I meant was that "Who I am is none of your concern" is not a possible fused relative construction. "Who I am" is an interrogative, where the meaning is "The answer to the question 'who am I?' is none of your concern".

Comment: Note also that CGEL makes it crystal clear that fused relative "who" only occurs in the 'free choice' construction.

Comment: @BillJ But you seem to have said earlier that there might be some exceptional cases where some non-'free choice' constructions could be headed by a fused relative word 'who': https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/94380/relative-pronoun-after-preposition

Comment: @BillJ Moreover, considering context outside the embedded portion determines whether it's a fused relative or interrogative construction, I don't understand how _how it looks_ in _I don’t like how it looks_ is a fused relative construction whereas _who you are_ in _you don't like who you are_ is an interrogative construction.

Comment: Re your link: after I posted that answer, Rodney Huddleston persuaded me that the subordinate clause in question was an interrogative clause, not a fused relative one. I now accept that fused relative "who" is restricted to the free choice construction.

Comment: @BillJ Thanks for confirming that with your earlier comment. Still, CaGEL does think of _I don’t like how it looks_ as having a fused relative construction. And I believe it's the context **outside** the embedded fused relative/interrogative construction** that determines the nature of the embedded construction. Then, how can _you don't like who you are_ in (2) be said to include a different construction (i.e., interrogative) than _I don’t like how it looks_?

Comment: @BillJ Might be good to update your comments on that ELL post then, no? And perhaps upvote MFI's excellent answer?

Comment: @Araucaria Thanks for letting me go back to the ELL post! Although you seem to think that MFI's post is the correct one, after re-reading his post, I became more doubtful about his answer. But I've belatedly noticed that Peter Shor provided a link to Pullum's 2005 blog post, which I think supports his answer, and quite probably answers my question as well. Since this blog post was written after CaGEL, no wonder CaGEL fails to cover the particular use of who as a fused relative pronoun outside the free choice construction.

Comment: @JK2 I 'm not sure GKP's post necessarily supports your thesis here (although it doesn't contradict it, necessarily). GKP's post there just states that a very small minority of speakers still use *who* as the head of fused relatives. It doesn't contradict his analysis of *That's a big part of who I am* etc.

Comment: @Araucaria What do you mean by "his analysis of _That's a big part of who I am_"? As far as I know, CaGEL doesn't have as an example _who I am_ as a complement of a preposition _of_. Moreover, in that blog post, GKP clearly states, "in _Can I help who's next?_ we have a fused relative construction: it's the object of **_help_**." Similarly, in _you don't like who you are_, _who you are_ is the object of **_like_**, which I think means that we have a fused relative construction in (2).

Comment: @JK2 Sorry old bean, was whizzing that off in a 2 min break. I meant of course *That's who I meant*. However, back to GKP's blog. Notice that "Can I help who's next" is ambiguous. Out of context, it would always be interpreted as an interrogative. And the vast majority speakers wouldn't have that construction in their version of standard English. They would have to say *Can I help whoever's next*. So I don't think that necessarily impinges on your particular examples. If I get time, I'll write an answer. However, pace BillJ, notice that CamGEL do, in fact, seem to suggest that ...

Comment: @JK2 this is not a simple open and shut case.

Comment: @Araucaria That _who's next_ in _Can I help who's next?_ "would always be interpreted as an interrogative" is just beyond me, if that's really what you're saying. GKP himself has painstakingly differentiated _Can I help who's next?_ from interrogative uses such as _I wonder who's next._

Comment: @JK2 No, he differentiated *this use* of "Can I help who's next?". Suppose you're being blamed for someone being next in a show at the theatre, but you're only the stage manager, not the director; you might easily say "Look, can I help who's next?". In a non service context, that's the kind of meaning that might easily be given to the sentence. (Although, admittedly, so many people are in service situations so often, that many have probably heard that usage before without paying too much attention to it - so perhaps I shouldn't have said *always* there!)

Comment: @Araucaria I've gone back to the post and re-read the whole thing, and no, he didn't say a thing about _Can I help who's next?_ possibly embedding an interrogative construction within. And as for your own example of non-service context, unfortunately, I'm probably too dumb to understand how the same question can mean something different depending on whether in service or non-service context. Frankly, I've got no clue what you're talking about.

Comment: @JK2 No, he didn't, and I didn't say he did! However, he's talking about a small group of people exceptionally using *who* as the head of a non-free choice fused relative in a specific context. That doesn't mean that there isn't a comparable sentence which - unexceptionally - uses an interrogative. The two meanings are "What can I do about the situation concerning who's next" and "Can I provide support to the next individual in the queue". One thing's for sure though, GKP's post gives no indication he thinks that the other interrogative examples from CaGEL actually involve fused relatives.

Comment: @Araucaria I'm still not sure how _Can I help who's next?_ can mean "What can I do about the situation concerning who's next?", but I agree with your last point. In fact, while re-reading his blog, I've realized that he was made aware of such exceptional uses of _who_ as a fused relative word no later than "up to about fifteen years ago," which means that he would have been fully aware of this peculiar construction when he was working on CaGEL. But note that the OP's examples (1) and (2) are not from CaGEL, and that CaGEL doesn't even deal with any variant of (1) or (2).

Comment: @JK2: Re: "I'm still not sure how *Can I help who's next?* can mean 'What can I do about the situation concerning who's next?'": Cf. "Can I help it if I [...]?", "I can't help who I am", etc.

Comment: cf. "I will help who's next" and "Can I help who I am?"  @JK2 makes the most sense here.

Comment: I cannot for the life of me see why CGEL would call the _how_ examples ‘marginal’ and grammatical in some dialects only. Both the examples they give are completely unremarkable to me, and the dialect-switcher in my head cannot conceive of a dialect where this is not so. Where would “I don’t like how it looks” or “We won’t change how we use X” be ungrammatical, or even anything but completely normal?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Actually, that makes two of us.

Comment: does this book have definitions of interrogative and relative pronouns?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "I don't like *it* how it looks" should be correct, by my estimate. This expansion(?) is similar to  "I am aware that *that* is not the usual case" / "I am aware that's odd". Now get offa that horse.

Answer (score 1):

```
(1) That's a big part of [who I am].
```

Relative pronoun.  This is a statement, not a question."Who I am" is a noun clause that is the object of the preposition "of".  (I am who)

```
(2) When that day comes, if you don't like [who you are], you're done.
```

Relative pronoun.  This is a statement, not a question."Who you are" is a noun clause that is the direct object of the verb "like". (you are who)

Indirect questions.

Comment: Please use quote formatting, rather than code formatting.

Comment: Can you be more specific how I do "quote formatting"?  I am new here.

Comment: No problem! Put a `> ` in front of the quote. You can read more on formatting here: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

I believe they are both relative words.

A relative word is used to refer to a subject that has already been mentioned. For example, in CaGEL example i and ii, the subject was represented by the relative word "What".

So if you were to replace the relative word "What" in example i and ii, you would end up with the same thing-"A faulty switch caused the trouble."

We can split "That's a big part of who I am." into:
"That", which is our first subject,
"is a big part of", which are connectors and the like,
"who",our relative word,
and "I am", our second subject.

Together, "That who I", or "(Subject 1)who(Subject 2)"
So, I believe that who is a relative word in this situation.

The confusion over this may be because of, firstly,"That" being a relative word by itself, which relates to a previously mentioned non-human subject, and, secondly, the word "Who" being used to relate to, again, a non-human subject, and lastly, "Who I am", being a phrase.

"When that day comes if you don't like who you are, you're done." seems to be quite obviously relative. "Who you are" is the subject, where who refers to the "you" in question.

My final argument would be that the word "Who" comes in "Who you are" and "Who I am". It is clear these are relating to You and I. Their counterparts, "Who am I" and "Who are you", are the ones that contain the interrogative "Who"s, asking about the identities of You and I.

Hope this explanation helps everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is an interesting one, and I am not surprised it is still floating around.

CGel can reasonably treat the *who* used in this type of context as a relative pronoun.  It would involve something like understanding an unstated "..is  who I am".  That is a reasonable way of looking at it.  Similarly, you can argue that it operates as an interrogative pronoun.  In that case "who I am" is indirect (reported) speech, where we are to understand "..is  who I am."  Either is defensible.

The first and obvious thing to say is that despite the now almost universal use of this fashionable idiom, dictionaries like Merriam Webster and the Cambridge English dictionaries do not seem to deal with it.  I can tell you what it means (as if you didn't know already).  Whenever its first use may be, I doubt (from memory) whether it can be found before 1990, and possibly not before 2000.

Understanding the expression has very little to do with grammar.  I mean that whoever its first users may have been, they are unlikely to have had a precise grammatical analysis in mind.  And whoever they were who caught onto and spread it around the English speaking world were not interested in the grammar of it either.  The fact that this saying is grammatically troubling is probably one reason for its catching on and spreading so widely.  What it is, I have learned from internet searches, is a **meme**, and indeed a *locus classicus* of a meme.  (By the way, *locus classicus* was probably a sort of meme of its own time (which ended during the second half of the 20th century).  It was known then (in my younger years) as a *Latin tag*, widely used by academics barristers and senior civil servants till the 1980s, when the British civil service and other banned them from their publications and communications!)

The expression "it is who I am" is used more than once by Chris Tomlinson, who has a song which uses the meme over and over again:- https://babylonbee.com/news/im-chris-tomlin-its-who-i-am-16x---op-ed-by-chris-tomlin.  Every verse consists of one repeated line as does the chorus (refrain)

> I'm Chris Tomlinson, it's **who** I am.

I shall not discuss the literary merits of this particular use of the meme.  But one thing is obvious, and that is that there is nothing grammatically troubling about it.  The use of the word '*who*' may be interrogative or relative.  It tells you the identity of the speaker.  Once I know your name is Chris Tomlinson, I know part of how to find you again.  Though there are many other people of that name, it's a good start.  It gives me information about your identity.

Then there is a song by Chris Young called *Who I Am with You*.  The song begins with an account of his making a bad start in life:  a rolling stone, and in general not much good.... until he meets his beloved, when, in a rising climax of volume and pitch, he declares that

> A better man is who I am with you.

This is different.  This is linking his quality as a person to to his identity.  But of course, if you ask the lucky girl who her boyfriend is, she is not going to answer:  "He's a better man", or "a good man".  She certainly is not going to have much luck asking any of her friends whether they know where this better man she met up with on holiday might live.  "Do you mean to tell us you didn't find out who he was?" they might ask incredulously.  So there is something queer about this locution.

The expression is often used to lay claim to particular personal qualities as their identity, or part of it.  Someone can also use it to assert that some pursuit or avocation is so important to them as to be part of their identity:  "musician/plumber/safe cracker/parent ... is who I am".  Without it I am nothing.  Before the meme came along, people would say "Musician is **what** I am, or "A better person is **what** I am".

The meme is, in other words part of the contemporary identity culture.  This meme asserts a person's right to the things that are most important to them:  things neither the state not society have the right to take away. This may involve personal qualities, possession, avocations or group memberships, national, ethnic, religious, gender and so on).  Such assertions are, to be sure, likely to be challenged by most people  at certain points:  people are unlikely to find many accepting an assertion that a safe cracker, multi billionaire, serial killer or prime minister of the UK is "who they are".  It raises questions, much debated, about whether a people can claim any kind of right to anything they lay claim to as "who I am".  But this is not a matter of English Language Usage.

Aside from that, the expression (meme) succeeds by being arresting. And part of that *arresting* quality has to do with a (let me call it) grammatically *stretched* use of the relative or interrogative *who* to cover "what kind of".

Answer (score 0):

In the two examples of the question, "who" is a relative pronoun.    CaGEL's "interrogative" examples are wrong.    Those sentences are simple predicate nominative constructions, with "who" as the head of the noun phrase in the predicate.

Comment: I'm not slavishly devoted to CGEL (2002), but challenging their analyses on ELU needs more than an unsupported counter-claim.

Answer (score 0):

(1) That's a big part of **who I am**.

"of" is a preposition that needs "noun" or "noun equivalents", so "who I am" is a noun equivalent.

An object of **"of"** is "who I am".

Who am I? ("Who" is an interrogative pronoun like Who are you?)

Back to the topic, we need to change "who am I" to "who I am" (Wh- S+V: the word order of an indirect question)

(2) When that day comes if you don't like **who you are**, you're done.

"like" is a preposition(the same as "of" like explained above)
"who you are" is an object of "like" which is a noun equivalent.

So both (1) and (2) are interrogative pronouns.

**※ fused pronoun needs antecedent**

ex) In “This is the house that Jack built,” house is the antecedent of that.("that" is an object of "built", "the house" is an antecedent)

I like a girl who lives next to my house.("who" is a subject of "lives", "a girl" is an antecedent)

I met a boy whose hair was red.("a boy" is an antecedent, "whose" is also a relative pronoun that possesses "hair")

There are three kinds of relative pronoun usage.

(1) the subjective case
(2) the objective case
(3) the possessive case (as shown above earlier)

Answer (score -2):

"who I am" as a declarative noun clause – object of "of" – would seem to rule out any interrogative function, actual or virtual.

Answer (score -3):

"Who" is a relative pronoun, not an interrogative pronoun. A relative pronoun is used to connect a clause or phrase to a noun or pronoun. Who, in fact, is one of the most common relative pronouns. An example is - "The driver **who** ran the stop sign was careless."

References  - **https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/pronouns/relative-pronoun.html**

Comment: “Who” can be either a relative pronoun or an interrogative pronoun.

Comment: This is quite obviously not accurate, and this kind of over-simplified, basic grammar link is certainly in no way an adequate answer to a question displaying this level of detail and sophistication.

Answer (score -3):

I am not a literacy or grammar expert, but for my own use I have (perhaps from a teacher long ago, who knows) a simple rule that if you would use the word "him" (that is ending with the "m") then you should use "whom".  I think Important people will have all sorts of names for the category of word but I just find that intuitively one can decide if it would be "he" or "him" in the sentence if it were unscrambled.

so "who I am" you would re-arrange it and using he/him it would read "I am HIM" not "I am HE" and thus I would suggest, tentatively and standing to be corrected, and all that sort of thing, that most of the question relates to sentences that would require WHOM.  of course some of these sentences would appear clumsy so we wouldn't say it at all.
Basically it could be both. Does this help?

Comment: Unlike some people on this site, I favor using "whom" when appropriate, but as the complement of "am" or "are" it is not appropriate. In order to correctly use the "he vs. him" criterion for "who vs. whom" decisions, one must learn to say "I am he."