# What's wrong with using a clause starting with 'how' as the object?

Tags: adverbs

'I don't like how he talks' - I'm sure that's wrong and should be changed to 'I don't like the way he talks' but I'm trying to work out what rule it breaks?

Comment: It's bad form to use "how" like that. For the expression to be object of "like" it would have to be an NP, as in your suggested alternant. I suspect the restriction exists because "how" is so strongly associated with interrrogatives that it simply 'sounds' wrong in declaratives. However, relative "how" is fine in the 'free choice' kind of 'fused relatives', as in "You can do it how you like".

Comment: It's a short distance from [an Oxford example](https://www.lexico.com/definition/how) "She told us how she had lived out of a suitcase for a week" to the OP sentence "I don't like how he talks". That short distance is very easily covered in speech; perhaps less so in written text.

Comment: It's not wrong; in fact, it's quite common.

Comment: CGEL:1077 marks "I don't like how it looks" as "grammatical in some dialects only". I am surprised at this, because it is unquestionably grammatical in my "dialect". It is a fused relative use of "how", not interrogative "how", and not (@Andrew Leach) a colloquial use of "how" meaning "that".

Comment: @Pax My examples are definitely **not** *that*: they are "the way that", an indication of method or manner, in much the same use as an interrogative. "She told us that she had lived out of a suitcase" is definitely not the same as "She described to us the way in which she had lived out of a suitcase", which is what that use of *how* should be taken to mean.

Comment: @Andrew. Thank you for the clarification.  I had in mind colloquialisms like "I don't like how he always has to be right” [2016], which use "how" more in the sense of "the fact that" than "the manner in which".  This has more in common with a subordinate declarative clause than the OP's fused relative.

Comment: @Pax It only occurs in the 'free choice' construction of the 'fused' relative construction, as I said in my earlier comment. I don't know why you mentioned interrogative "how", since "how he talks" is certainly not a subordinate interrogative clause. Nevertheless, in examples like "I don't know [how he did it]", "how he did it" is interrogative.

Comment: @BillJ. I mentioned interrogative "how" only to rule it out. However, the OP's example is a fused relative "how" which is not a free-choice construction.  The example I cited above is from CGEL:1077; they acknowledge it as a fused relative but they consider it "rare and quite marginal".  I consider it neither.

Comment: The ngram[1] shows "don't like the way" as about three times more popular than "don't like how".  However, the latter now has a substantial following, given that it was barely used 40 years ago.[1]: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=don%27t%20like%20how%2Cdon%27t%20like%20the%20way&corpus=26&year_end=2019&year_start=1800&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdo%20not%20like%20how%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdo%20not%20like%20the%20way%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdo%20not%20like%20how%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdo%20not%20like%20the%20way%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Pax I know the OP's example is not the free choice kind. But I think it's important to bring out the point that it's only the 'free choice' construction of the 'fused' relative construction tax is widely accepted, while in other kinds of fused relative "how" is only marginally acceptable, i.e. in some dialects only.

Comment: @BillJ.  I'm curious to know which dialects it is still considered ungrammatical in.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the use of "how" here is still considered grammatically substandard in some quarters, whereas "the way" is universally accepted.  Therefore you might want to use the latter in more formal settings.

It is certainly true that "the way" is the older and more established usage, though "how" has become increasingly acceptable [since 1980](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=don%27t%20like%20how%2Cdon%27t%20like%20the%20way&corpus=26&year_end=2019&year_start=1800&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdo%20not%20like%20how%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdo%20not%20like%20the%20way%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdo%20not%20like%20how%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdo%20not%20like%20the%20way%3B%2Cc0), when it was barely used.

"I don't like how he looks" raised no eyebrows among either American or British speakers on [WordReference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/how-he-looks.3566816/).

In my own BrE circle "how" is widely accepted, and a quick google of the New York Times suggests that it is also common currency in AmE:
*They don't like how he's doing his job [2010].
I just don't like how they fit on me [2015].
I don't like how I appear in the mirror now [2020].*

Nevertheless, the Cambridge Grammar 2002 marks it as "grammatical in some dialects only".  Whether this is the case in 2020 is, to my mind, dubious.

Comment: Could you give page refs for the CaGEL?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: I think it's the part mentioned in [JK2's question here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/443384/is-who-here-a-relative-word-or-an-interrogative-pronoun):  "Here's what CaGEL (Page 1076-77) says about 'how' marginally occurring in a fused relative:

Examples with how are found but they are rare and quite marginal:

%We will not change how we use future contracts during the term of this Prospectus; %I don’t like how it looks."

Comment: @herisson Thanks. It's actually in Pax's comments under the question. I was just encouraging them to put that info in their post so that I could upvote them. I'm very familiar with that bit of text.

Answer (score -2):

The reason it might break in some dialects, is that “how” is not accepted as a complementizer, but merely as an adverb in them.

A complementizer is a part of speech that allows a sentence to function as a nominal phrase, thus allowing it to serve as the subject or object as a sentence. “that” is the quintessential example:

> That I love him is true.

> I know that you love him.

In this case “that I love him” and “that you love him” function as subject and object respectively of their matrix clauses, thus allowing a sentence to function in that role.

Another complementizer would be “whether” which creates a nominalized sentence with a different nuance.

In “I don't like [object].” a nominal object is demanded by the grammar. Of course “the way he talks” is itself a nominal phrase with the sentence “he talks” qualifying the noun phase “the way”, as such “the way he talks” is certainly a nominal phrase and can fulfill such roles as subject or object of a sentence or serve as the object of an adpositional.

“how” was originally an interrogative adverb but in most dialects of English seems to have taken on the function of a complementizer as well. — dialects that reject “*I like how he talks.*” thus reject this function of the word, and would also be expected to reject sentences such as: “*How he talks sounds fine to me.*”, where it functions as the subject of a sentence.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementizer

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I don't see why. I know of no English dialect that accepts. \*“*What I love him is true.*” or \*“*Where I love him is true.*”.

Comment: That's because they make no sense. they are nonethteless grammatical. It's acceptable to say e.g. "What I said is true" or "Where I hang my hat is home".

Comment: @RosieF that's not a complementizer, “what I said” is a free relative clause with the pronoun “what” taking the place of the object in the sentence. A complementizer takes a complete sentence. One can say “*That I said this thing is true.*” but not “*What I said this thing is true.*” as “what I said this thing” is not a valid free relative clause, as “I said this thing” already contains it's object, which must be omitted.

Comment: @Zorf The OP gives "I don't like the way he talks" a a replacement for "'I don't like how he talks". That suggested to me that they were using "how" as a relative adverb; did I misunderstand?

Comment: @RosieF it is indeed a complementizer in “*I like how he talks.*”. A relative pronoun or adverb namely, as said, takes the place of a part of the sentence, which it relates to. The difference can be observed by that “*I like how he talks so.*” is accepted as “how” does not replace it's counterpart “so”, but for instance in “*I drink where I eat there.*” is not accepted as “where I eat” is indeed a free relative clause, and “where” replaces the locative adverb of the sentence and thus “where” and “there” cannot exist in the same sentence.

Comment: @Zorf I don't understand your example “I like how he talks so.” which you say is accepted. And if your comment proved that "how" is a complementizer in "I like how he talks”, then I don't see it. "I like what he says" means "I like the things he says"; "what..." is a relative clause. "I like where you eat" means "I like the place you eat"; "where..." is a relative clause. To return to the OP, "I don't like how he talks" means "I don't like the way he talks"; "how he talks" seems to be a relative clause like the others; how come it isn't?